# What complexity class is this?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines, finite-automata

***Disclaimer 1: I am a beginner in this domain and I am self-learning these concepts. Please take this in consideration when reading my question.***

***Disclaimer 2: All corrections to this question are highly encouraged. All self-learning PDF books etc. that helped you better understand these particular concepts are highly desired.***

Hello,

In this question, I assume I have some formal definition of the Turing machine such that:

1. any Turing machine (say $M$) can receive exactly:

   - one input $i$, where $i \in \{0,1\}^*$ ;
   - one witness $w$, where $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ and $\exists \, a \in \mathbb{N} : |w| \le |i|^a$. I call such a witness "a witness of the input $i$". By $|x|$ I mean the length of the string $x$.
2. $M$ is able to compute with $i$ and $w$ and:

   - loop, if the computation lasts forever. I write $M(i, w) = {\nearrow}$ to denote this
   - halt, if the computation ends at some point. Here, there are two "types" of halting:

     - accept, if the computation ends in some accepting state. I write $M(i, w) = 1$ to denote this
     - reject, otherwise. I write $M(i, w) = 0$ to denote this.

I have recently read on Wikipedia that the definition of the $P$ class is the following:

> A language L is in P if and only if there exists a deterministic Turing machine M, such that
>
> - M runs for polynomial time on all inputs
> - For all x in L, M outputs 1
> - For all x not in L, M outputs 0
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexity)

I adapted the definition to my Turing machine model as follows:

> A language L is in P if and only if there exists a Turing machine M, such that
>
> - For all inputs x, $\exists \, a \in \mathbb{N} : \mathbb{T}[M,x,\varepsilon] \le |x|^a$.
>   I write $\varepsilon$ for the empty string. By $\mathbb{T}[M,i,w]$ I mean the number of time units required in the computation of $M$ with $i$ and $w$.
> - For all x in L, $M(x, \varepsilon) = 1$
> - For all x not in L, $M(x, \varepsilon) = 0$

I am searching to define a complexity class where exactly the same rules of $P$ apply to both the input and the witness. Therefore, ***I want to define this***:

> A language L is in ... (insert complexity class name here) if and only if there exists a Turing machine M, such that
>
> - For all inputs x and for all witnesses w of x, $\exists \, a \in \mathbb{N} : \mathbb{T}[M,x,w] \le |x|^a$
> - For all x in L and for all witnesses w of x, $M(x, w) = 1$
> - For all x not in L and for all witnesses w of x, $M(x, w) = 0$

As I see it, it would obviously be a superset of $P$ (since for all inputs $i$, we have $\varepsilon \in \{ w : w \text{ is a witness of } i \}$).

***QUESTION: Did someone already propose before a complexity class that satisfies my above definition?***

What I don't know is whether there is a widely-known name for this specific complexity class (as we have with $P$, $PSPACE$, $EXP$ etc.) or I should define it on my own (with some arbitrary name, say $P_{+W}$?)

Thank you for looking over my question!

**P. S.** I have previously found the class $ZPP$ as an almost-good candidate for the answer to my question, but because I read on Wikipedia the following:

> if the algorithm is allowed to flip a truly-random coin while it is running, it will always return the correct answer and, for a problem of size n, there is some polynomial p(n) such that the average running time will be less than p(n), even though it might occasionally be much longer
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPP_(complexity)

I have understood that the average running time (i.e., the ***average*** of all running times) will be polynomially bounded, whereas, with my class, I want ***all*** running times to be polynomially bounded, just like in $P$. Did I understand anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this

> For all inputs x, $\exists \, a \in \mathbb{N} : \mathbb{T}[M,x,\varepsilon] \le |x|^a$.

is wrong for the definition of P. Every terminating Turing machine will satisfy this condition. Why? Because the choice of the exponent $a$ depends on the input $x$, the time complexity can be $|x|^{|x|}$ for example.

The correct definition uses the swapped order qualifiers like $\exists a\forall x, T(x) \leq |x|^a$.

Now, the main question

> - For all x in L and for all witnesses w of x, $M(x, w) = 1$
> - For all x not in L and for all witnesses w of x, $M(x, w) = 0$

This is just P. You wrote:

> As I see it, it would obviously be a superset of $P$ (since for all inputs $i$, we have $\varepsilon \in \{ w : w \text{ is a witness of } i \}$).

but this argument actually shows the language class in the question is a *subset* of P.

Think this way: you are given a Turing machine satisfying the conditions. Can you recognize the given language in polynomial time? Yes, we can simulate $M$ with the empty witness, and output the result.

It is also easy to show the language class in the question contains P because the witness can just be discarded. Therefore, the language class in the question is P.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will mark it as the correct answer, but would it be possible for you to edit your answer and make a very quick math demonstration of the last two paragraphs for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @QwertyBoy Not sure which part you don't understand. The only argument used is that $(\forall w, P(w))$ implies $P(\varepsilon)$ for any proposition $P$. Also note that $\forall x, \forall w, P(x,w)$ iff $\forall w, \forall x, P(x,w)$ therefore it implies $\forall x, P(x, \varepsilon)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!